# Create custom layout product list woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to make a list of products woocommerce as warungssl..com shown are: the product name, normal price, discount prices, some attributes,  link or button that leads to a product detail page, and a link or button cart.

[image]

In Which file should I change the script code and I do not understand how to display multiple attributes.

Note:
 1. To (issuance, validation, and site seal) I will call the attribute
    data. The obstacles I did not understand the script.
 2. I make use of Wordpress themes porto
 3. The following examples are meant attributes

[image]

Maybe it could let me know where the location of the files that I have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
please go to here : wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\archive-product.php
or 
please go to here : wp-content\themes\porto\woocommerce\archive-product.php


and put following code:
<?php
global $product;

$greenbar = $product->get_attribute( 'greenbar' );
$issuance = $product->get_attribute( 'issuance' );
$mobile_friendly = $product->get_attribute( 'mobile_friendly' );
$san_support = $product->get_attribute( 'san_support' );
$site_seal = $product->get_attribute( 'site_seal' );
$validation = $product->get_attribute( 'validation' );
$warranty = $product->get_attribute( 'warranty' );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks For Response :)